# trouble with calling exe file from matlab

Tags: matlab, exe

I had some .m files packaged in an .exe file by using compiler toolbox of matlab.
When I tried to run it by both clicking and calling from matlab (using 'system' command), it failed with this error!

```
Could not find the version  8.1 of the MCR
Attempting to load mclmcrrt8_1.dll
Pealse install the corect version of the MCR
Contact your vendor if you do not have an installer for the MCR
```

After installing correct version of MCRInstaller, I could run the .exe file by clicking on it, but attempting to call it from matlab (using 'system' command) still failed with that error. :(
Could any one help me with this problem! I'm using Win8.1 and Matlab 2013a.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Was the executable compiled with the same version of matlab you are using (2013a)  ?

Comment: Thank you for your caring! This fail because i added files not correctly when i build my project and I have fixed it